# select date column followed by (DATE)

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi this might be a basic question but I can't seem to find other resources that touch upon this, so I see in our company's SQL query for Teradata something like:

```
select * from table
where start_date(DATE) between CURRENT_DATE-90 and CURRENT_DATE
```

What does the `(DATE)` do here? Is it casting the column to date type? Thanks.

Comment: `start_date(DATE)` is old syntax, same as `cast(start_date as date)`

Comment: @dnoeth ah thank you! would (Date start_date) achieve the same thing?

Comment: you should cast it, just as Dieter proposed, that'll do the trick. Assuming start_date is a varchar field. If it's a date already, you can simply say "where start_date between ..."

Comment: `(Date start_date)`: DATE is the same as CURRENT_DATE, thus it would result in a column named start_date with today's value (in a Select list, in WHERE it will fail). Assuming that start_date is a timestamp (e.g. from QryLogV) there's no need to cast it because comparing DATE & TIMESTAMP automatically cast the timestamp to date.